# JPA - Successful Storage of Post Only When Input Tag Name is "file"

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, jpa, thymeleaf

I'm implementing a feature to store posts using JPA. In the service class, I have the following method:

```
public void boardWrite(Board board, MultipartFile file) throws Exception, IOException {
    if (!file.isEmpty()) {
        String path = "E:\\image\\sell";
        UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
        String filename = uuid + "_" + file.getOriginalFilename();
        File saveFile = new File(path, filename);
        file.transferTo(saveFile);
        board.setPhoto(filename);
        board.setPhoto_url("/sell/" + filename);
    }

    boardRepository.save(board);
}
```

Additionally, in the controller, I call it as follows:

```
@PostMapping("/add")
public String add(Board board, MultipartFile file) throws Exception {
    service.boardWrite(board, file);
    return "redirect:list";
}
```

The part of the HTML where I get the file input is as follows:

```
<tr>
    <td width="150" align="center">Photo Attachment</td>
    <td>
        <input type="file" name="file" class="form-control" id="inputGroupFile02">
    </td>
</tr>
```

When I set the name attribute of the input tag to "file", the post is successfully stored. However, if I use a different name such as "file1" or "photo", it results in a 400 error. I'm curious about the reason behind this behavior. Why does it only work when the input tag name is "file"?

Comment: Thats the name of the field you give the form to transmit. `MultipartFile file` searches for the `file` field in the body, so these names must match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The argument `MultipartFile file` is equivalent to: `@RequestParam MultipartFile file`

If you don't specify a name with the `@RequestParam` annotation the variable name is used as default.  In your case this is `file`.

You can use other names by either changing your variable name or adding the `@RequestParam` annotation with a name:
`@RequestParam("photo") MultipartFile file`.

If you have to support multiple names, create proxy methods:

```java
@PostMapping(value="/add", params = "photo")
public String addPhoto(@RequestParam(value="photo", required=true) MultipartFile file){
   return addFile(file);
}

@PostMapping(value="/add", params = "file")
public String addFile(@RequestParam(value="file", required=true) MultipartFile file){
   // ...
}
```